# How to make a program that stores user inputs into array list

Tags: java, arraylist, user-input

I am making a program that asks for the user's name and ID. Those two inputs should be stored into an array list and show it to the user.

Once the user inputs his/her info the program will randomly ask 10 multiple choice questions created by me. Their answers will be stored in an array list and show it the user.

How is it possible to do this with Java?

```
Full name:
ID: 

How many stars is there in the USA flag?
A. 50
B. 25
C.400
D. 1
Answer:
```

(The question will be already added in the code. It will randomly select the questions.)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AAA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> phone = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
            name.add(sc.next());
            System.out.println("Please enter your ID: ");
            phone.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried doing? Show your code and explain where the problem is

Comment: The first step, in all honesty, would be to start with some tutorials on Java and begin developing your program.  We can help with specific problems you encounter in your code, but we can't teach you Java.

Answer (score 1):

Java provides a class called Random create an object of it and make it produces random integer values where the maximum number is the length of the ArrayList